# How to export excel column data that contains existing HTML in each row

Tags: excel, office365

I've got a DB export that has information for a number of companies - There are 4 rows of information per company; LossExperience, CoverNotes, InsuredSummaryOperation and PricingRationale

Each of these rows has their "information" as HTML in another column.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get these displayed. It would be great if I could export an HTML file for each company with the 4 rows of information on it but I'm not sure how to do that, and each row is a full HTML page starting with  so not sure how that would format.

Any help would be appreciated! (BTW if you know a better way for me to copy/paste this excel data in let me know)

[image: Was too much text to paste so I've had to do a screenshot,]

| id | company | information | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 | LossExperience | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 1 | Company 1 | CoverNotes | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 1 | Company 1 | InsuredSummaryOperation | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 1 | Company 1 | PricingRationale | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 2 | Company 2 | LossExperience | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 2 | Company 2 | CoverNotes | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 2 | Company 2 | InsuredSummaryOperation | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |
| 2 | Company 2 | PricingRationale | `<html>there's html code in here</html>` |

Edit: I've added the table to see it better

Comment: You should paste comment text and exact data you want to extract.

Comment: @user11222393 It's too large I think

Comment: @user11222393 I added the table with an example of how the data is

Comment: The problem is that it is hard to tell best method to extract data from html code without seeing it. Can only guess if structure is always same, whether it lies between between repeated tags and etc. One of approaches would be to use TEXTAFTER and TEXTBEFORE combined

Comment: @user11222393 For me, it doesn't matter what the HTML is. Just take into account that it's there.

Comment: So what is expected result?

Comment: @user11222393 I would like each "company" to have an an HTML file exported using the contents of the HTML in the comments section